# How to override named dependency in Unity

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, overriding, unity-container

please suggest me how to solve the following problem:

I have a class:

```
public class Module
{
   public Module(Uri param1, Uri param2)
   {
   }
}
```

This type is registered in The Unity Container:

```
container.RegisterInstance<Uri>("uri1", new Uri("http://sample-1.com"));
container.RegisterInstance<Uri>("uri2", new Uri("http://sample-2.com"));

container.RegisterType<Module>(
       new InjectionConstructor(
             new ResolvedParameter<Uri>("uri1"), 
             new ResolvedParameter<Uri>("uri2")));
```

In this way I'm builded dependency to different constructor parameters to different instances of Uri.

I want override this values while resolving instance of Module.

I can override by type:

```
container.Resolve<Module>(
             new DependencyOverride(typeof(Uri), new Uri("http://overriden.com")))
```

Also I can override by custructor parameters.

```
container.Resolve<Module>(
   new ParameterOverride("param1", new Uri("http://param1.org"))
   new ParameterOverride("param2", new Uri("http://param2.com")))
```

BUT: I don't know how to override by type according to name of type registration.
So, DependencyOverride doesn't have any additional parameters for overriding not all types and cannot use named registrations.

Therefore, I would like have something like the following:

```
container.Resolve<Module>(
    new DependencyOverride("uri1", typeof(Uri), new Uri("http://overriden-1.com")),
    new DependencyOverride("uri2", typeof(Uri), new Uri("http://overriden-2.com")));
```

Where the first parameter (uri1 & uri2) is the names that was used to build dependencies while registering type by using ResolvedParameter("uri1") and ResolvedParameter("uri2") on initial registration.

Please, suggest me, how I can override while resolving Module from a container without defining names of constructor parameters.

P.S. Why do I want go to this way?
Because I don't want have dependency on name of parameters, someone can rename their and dependency tree will broken. Also, I don't want have dependency of how Module was registered, what kind of constructor was chosen if Module has more than one constructor.

UPD: I found temporarily solution, but it's just workaround, because it broke lifetime managers, for instance PerResolveLifetimeManager due to the fact that we are resolving Module1 and Module2 separately from controller, that have dependency to Module1 and Module2.

```
        var m1 = _container.Resolve<IModule1>(
            new DependencyOverride(typeof(HttpControllerContext), context),
            new DependencyOverride(typeof(Uri), new Uri("http://module-1.com/")));

        var m2 = _container.Resolve<IModule2>(
            new DependencyOverride(typeof(HttpControllerContext), context),
            new DependencyOverride(typeof(Uri), new Uri("http://m-2.com/")));

        var dependency = new ResolverOverride[] 
        {
            new DependencyOverride(typeof(HttpControllerContext), context),
            new DependencyOverride(typeof(IModule1), m1),
            new DependencyOverride(typeof(IModule2), m2)
        };

        var controller = _container.Resolve(controllerType, dependency) as IHttpController;
        return controller;
```

Comment: What about changing the value or "uri1" in the configuration instead of working with derivates of `ResolverOverride`?

Comment: Of course I can, but it cannot help me to solve my issue of how to override constructor parameters without dependencies to names of constructor parameters. I would like override only by types. But you suggest me another approach how to solve this. If it will help, I will write response how I done it.

Comment: I would even suggest that you don't call the container anywhere in your application code outside the composition root to be honest... Would you mind to share a bit of code that shows how and where you call the container in the way you described above?

Comment: I was more interested in where this snippet was located than in the actual workaround. Where do you get the various instances of `Uri` from?

Comment: I was replace the type Uri while resolving IModule1 & Module2 by using DependencyOverride

Comment: That code looks so horribly wrong but I can't tell you how to fix it unless I get the whole picture.

Comment: The main goal is a late binding. You see, I have module that requires a couple other modules, but the important parameter  -Uri can be defined only when IModule is resolving.

In the other words, I want inject request Uri to all modules that requires current request Uri, but some of them require transformed request Uri. Therefore, I cannot define those values on initial registration phase. I see only one way: Override dependencies on resolving.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a child container? Instead of

```
container.Resolve<Module>(
    new DependencyOverride("uri1", typeof(Uri), new Uri("http://overriden-1.com")),
    new DependencyOverride("uri2", typeof(Uri), new Uri("http://overriden-2.com")));
```

you could create a child container with your URIs, and let it to resolve your module:

```
container.CreateChildContainer()
    .RegisterInstance<Uri>("uri1", new Uri("http://overriden-1.com"))
    .RegisterInstance<Uri>("uri2", new Uri("http://overriden-2.com"))
    .Resolve<Module>();
```